# Direct3D 9.0 Interleaved non-fvf Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I am trying to interleave vertex data into an STL container of std vector template. I have successfully done this with OpenGL already, the source code of my mesh interface is available online for my open source project...
https://github.com/RobertBColton/enigma-dev/blob/master/ENIGMAsystem/SHELL/Graphics_Systems/OpenGL3/GL3model.cpp

Now I want to do the same method using DirectX and have already managed to do so partially by logical xor'ing my FVF DWORD together with what components of each vertex I have.  However this is what the mesh currently renders as when it contains only vertices and normals:

[image]

Now DX makes this very difficult for me to do the same thing I was doing in OGL, I have checked, double checked, and checked over and over again and my byte alignment is perfect inside the buffer. What I am trying to do can be better explained by the OpenGL Wiki...
/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices#Formatting_VBO_Data

Now I do not want to implement a shader to accomplish this either. If anyone could simply offer me any pointers on what I am trying to do or point me in the direction of an example or tutorial of doing this in Direct3D 9 it would really help me out as this does not seem to be very common practice in DX.

Comment: If you read the vertex specifications best practices, it also tells you not to use floating-point colors. RGB float is a T&L-friendly format on old hardware but RGBA is not. RGBA ubyte is T&L-friendly and also takes 1/4 the storage space. RGBA ubyte is also the format D3D uses for things like D3DFVF_DIFFUSE, though it's in ARGB order.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! But as for the triangleCount, that is not the count of triangles, that is the count of elements by indices, I think you were a tad confused in that part of my code. The OpenGL version already works fine http://oi39.tinypic.com/2w53cqv.jpg. But thank you for the information on that is really useful, do you have any suggestions how I could change it since I am using a vector of type gs_scalar (which stands for graphics system scalar, whose default is float) ?

Comment: What I would do is use a std::vector <SomeStruct> instead of a std::vector <float>. That's the usual approach to interleaved formats. Something like struct { float pos [3]; float normal [3]; DWORD color; float tex_st [2]; } // <-- D3D9... D3D has a macro you can use to pack floating-point colors into a DWORD, `D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE (r,g,b,a)`. With the right format and data type for vertex color (`GL_BGRA`, `GL_UNISNGED_BYTE`) you should also be able to use this data structure interoperably in OpenGL too.

Comment: Well you see that is entirely what I am trying to avoid, sometimes this mesh class can be passed normals and sometimes it might not be, so any single instance of this model does not have a uniform vertex format. That is my entire problem.

Comment: Well, there's a finite number of combinations :P You'll have maybe 3-4 variations of the vertex structure the way I see it in your code currently. Or, you can still use a vector of floats for this, technically since GLfloat and DWORD are both 32-bit. Just tell OpenGL you're using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_BGRA` for the color. You can always get a pointer to the float and cast it to a DWORD pointer before shimming the DWORD color into it. Same goes for D3D, just use the appropriate FVF bitmask and ignore the fact that the entire thing is laid out as a vector of floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closer inspection of what you are trying to do here, I believe this is what you want:

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 custom_vertex [] =
{
  { 0,  0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3,   D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0 },
  { 0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3,   D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_NORMAL,   0 },
  { 0, 24, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2,   D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 0 },
  { 0, 32, D3DDECLTYPE_D3DCOLOR, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR,    0 },
  D3DDECL_END()
};
```

The format of this data structure is pretty similar to OpenGL's Vertex Pointer system, you have to pass in the offset, the size and number of components (e.g. `D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3`). You also include the purpose of the field (e.g. `D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR`). Unlike OpenGL, D3D can calculate the stride for you simply through use of the `D3DDECL_END()` macro.

```
IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9* vertex_declaration;
d3dDevice->CreateVertexDeclaration (custom_vertex, &vertex_declaration);
```

Now you should be good to go and create and fill your vertex buffer using this declaration. You can add/remove the elements as need be by using a different D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 array.

Do remember to use a DWORD (D3D) or 4 ubyte (OpenGL) colors though. There is no reason to use floating-point colors a good 90% of the time. They just waste storage and memory bandwidth.

Comment: Oh man you are the best! I got it all working perfectly, except models with color values are not getting the correct alpha my code is available again online for the DirectX version now https://github.com/RobertBColton/enigma-dev/blob/master/ENIGMAsystem/SHELL/Graphics_Systems/Direct3D9/DX9model.cpp

Comment: This is what it should and does look like in OpenGL http://oi39.tinypic.com/2w53cqv.jpg